# AutoMapper: IncludeBase only working if the Base-Profile is loaded

Tags: c#, automapper

It seems like the useful AutoMapper-Profile Property IncludeBase works only, if the base profile is already loaded. Here a theoretical example:

```
        CreateMap<BusinessObject, MainObject>()
        // Emitted

        CreateMap<BusinessObject, Child1>()
        .IncludeBase<BusinessObject, MainObject>()
        // Emitted, more properties
```

This one would work as expected, with Child1 getting all Properties of MainObject mapped.
Now, the other side arround, this doesn't work:

```
        CreateMap<BusinessObject, Child1>()
        .IncludeBase<BusinessObject, MainObject>()
        // Emitted, more properties

        CreateMap<BusinessObject, MainObject>()
        // Emitted
```

Only the Properties directly defined in the Child1 Profile get mapped correctly.

All the usages I had for AutoMapper inlcuded a dynamic loading of Profiles via Reflection. This behavior would obviously stop that, since I can't be sure, in which order the Profiles are loaded. Is this really intended or did I use something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just hit the reason why I've moved AutoMapper to instance-based and read-only configuration. You hit bugs like this. In AutoMapper 5.0 all these are fixed as I moved configuration to a two-step process, gathering all the configuration, then applying it in the correct order.

This is a bug, fixed in 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the verification, nothing is worse than the unknown